# How do I add a span inside a referenceBlock in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am attempting to add a fairly simple link to the top menu in a Magento 2 store. I have successfully added a standard link using a simple CSS class. But I am stuck on how to add a link with more complex spans within the link.

The link needs to look something like this in the output HTML:

```
<a href="<shop link here>" class="special-format">Request a <span class="very-special-format-here">Quote</span> <span class="special-format-here">></span></a>
```

I have added the necessary elements to the layout/default.xml file like this:

```
<argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="false"><link text here></argument>
<argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="false"><link here></argument>
<argument name="class" xsi:type="string">special-format</argument>
```

I've tried to add a CDATA element into the label, but unfortunately it just outputs the contents of the CDATA on screen.

Anybody any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a good deal of poking around I've answered my own question. I've resorted to a template. With blocks you can effectively render them through your own template file.

This is done in two places. In your custom theme `layout/default.xml` file add something like this:

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link"
       name="requestquote.link"
       before="my-account-link"
       template="Magento_Theme::html/requestquotelink.phtml" />
```

Then you need to implement the template file, in this case `requestquotelink.phtml`. This file goes into your custom theme's `Magento_Theme/templates/html` folder.

My requestqotelink.phtml is just plain html and is very simple:

```
<?php
    /**
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */
    ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<your link here>" class="some-class"><span>Request a <span \
    class="something-else">quote</span> <span class="nice-text">&gt;</span></span></a>
    </li>
```

Hope that helps.